# How do you get rid of hand prints on a pine table from under a treatment of colored danish oil?

Tags: staining, varnishing

I was varnishing a new unfinished pine table, and decided to use a fine sandpaper over the surface of the table. While doing this I rested my hand on the table, and might have left some sweat/body oil on the table. This was not visible on the unfinished table, but soon as I started applying the stain/Danish oil I noticed a lot of my hand prints appear in a few spots on the table.

I could sand down the entire finish and restart, but short of that, is there any other way that I can mask / get rid of those hand prints?

Comment: Many  wear gloves to do this type of work.

Answer (score 1):

You might try applying another coat of the stain/oil, applying it using superfine (0000) steel wool. Rub it in with the grain. This may help break up the residual film you left and let the stain penetrate a bit.

If it doesn't work, you'll be no worse off if you have to sand and refinish.